# How to position a ul element over a background link-image?

Tags: html, css

I want to position the  `<ul>` element over the background link-image (black square).

To the right of the words "ABOUT" and "CONTACTS",  I cannot click on the link image. 
I need to be be able to click on the background link-image every where outside of the
link texts.

Here is what I have tried: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktoto/hcky3gfx/)

**HTML**:

```
<div class="weekend">
<a href="/all">
     <img src="http://cdn.allfun.md/2014/01/23/10/52e0cd02e892f.jpg">
</a>         
<ul class="all">
    <li class="about"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li class="contacts"><a href="/contacts">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
.all{
    position: absolute;
    width: 290px;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;

}

.about{
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.contacts{
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Do you mean this? - http://jsfiddle.net/hcky3gfx/2/ Just remove the width value from the `ul`

Comment: No, right and left from the word "ABOUT" again I can not click on the black square

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: because you've set `width: 290px;` to your `ul.all` tag, I've removed the width in that demo and this may works for you - http://jsfiddle.net/hcky3gfx/4/

Comment: need the background `.all` to be transparent, and can be clicked to 
to link

Comment: I think you're after this - http://jsfiddle.net/hcky3gfx/7/ As you can see you have to position each element separately.

Comment: I've improved @Paulie_D fiddle, check - http://jsfiddle.net/hcky3gfx/9/

Comment: @Paulie_D There is a simpler alternative that does not require positioning each link element, see my post, thank!

Comment: @MaryMelody There is a simpler alternative that does not require positioning each link element, see my post, thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it without having to absolutely positioning each link.

Start with your HTML:

```
<div class="weekend">
    <a href="/all">
         <img src="http://cdn.allfun.md/2014/01/23/10/52e0cd02e892f.jpg">
    </a>         
    <ul class="all">
        <li class="about"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li class="contacts"><a href="/contacts">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And modify your CSS as follows:

```css
.weekend {
    position: relative;
}
.all {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px; /* Set to a small value, 0 will also work */
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px dashed yellow;
}
.all li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;   
    border: 1px dotted yellow;
}
.about{
    font-weight: 700;
}
.contacts{
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

First: set `position: relative` to `.weekend`, that way `ul.all` is positioned with respect
to its parent block container.

For `ul.all`, zero out the margin and padding to reset any unwanted whitespace, and
then set `display: inline-block` to get a shrink-to-fit width.

For the link link elements, `ul.all li`, use `display: inline-block` which will
give you better control over padding and margins if needed.

The key point now is to set the width of `ul.all` to a small value, 10px for example,
(0 also works).  This shrinks the edges of `ul.all` so that they no longer extend
beyond the edges of the `li` link elements, so you can then click on the background
element outside of the edges of the inline boxes containing the link text.

Essentially, the `ul.all li` elements are overflowing outside the edges of the parent
`ul.all` container, which is a bit odd but in this case, exactly what is needed.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/91ea4tfw/

Note that you can add top/bottom margins to `ul.all li` and the resulting whitespace
will also allow you to click on background link-image.  In this case, be sure to 
set `width: 0` to `ul.all` and remove the yellow border (for demo only).